# how to import module from same level directory in python

Tags: python, python-import

as the question, i have my directory map like this

[image]

[image]

the **formatOutput** contain some function for better print
now, i want use a function in module **printChecked.py** in package **formatOutput** from **findInfoSystem.py**

i have tried create `__init__.py` in all folder to treat python it is a package (the advice i get from previous answer other post) but it always failed.

case 1: `from formatOutput.printChecked import print_checked_box`

> error is: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'formatOutput'`

case 2: `from dttn.formatOutput.printChecked import print_checked_box`

> error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dttn'`

case 3: `from ..formatOutput.printChecked import print_checked_box`

> error is `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

i don't want to use the sys.path method because i think it is not the good way to solve problem.

Help me please !

Comment: in which file you try to import it ? it can change everything. And I think `sys.path` can be the best way.

Comment: @furas i try to import printChecked.py to findInfoSystem.py. I am using sys.path as a alternative way now, but as i know, it is a code smell, this project extremely important for me so i want to make it best work

Comment: as for me `formatOutput` and `module1` are like two different modules and using `sys.path` seems the best way.

Answer (score 1):

i found something very weird. I'm not import direct in module file but import to **init**.py file of package and then import to module file from packages name and it work. it like that:

from `__init__.py` of systemInfo package:

```
import sys,os
from formatOutput import prettyAnnounce,prettyParseData
current_directory = os.getcwd() 
# sys.path.insert(1, current_directory+"/formatOutput/")
# sys.path.insert(1,current_directory+"/")
```

then in findInfoSystem.py module, im imported again like this:

```
from systemInfo import current_directory, prettyAnnounce as prCh , prettyParseData as prPD
```

yeah, now it's work like a charm. :))) i even not sure how

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes of solutions to this problem:

1. modify the python import path
2. use the various setup tools or manually install .egg-links or symbolic links
   to "install" your development modules in the python/lib/site-packages

The first approach is simple, but the second involves delving deeper
into a number of related topics.  You'd probably want a virtual environment,
and a setup.py, etc.

So for the quick and dirty, two ways to modify the python import path:

1. set the PYTHONPATH= environment variable to include the parent directory of your packages
2. in findInfoSystem before importing formatOutput.printChecked, add this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

Comment: i using import sys as a alternaltive method now. But i want to find a built-in official method to make this work. seem a little bit hard.

Comment: The official method means writing a setup.py to install your module.  This is kind of a big topic.  https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html

Comment: If both packages are part of a related system, they could also be subpackages of an outer package.  This changes the import approach - then you could use `..` for relative imports.